# Get full html code from wicket

Tags: wicket

I am trying to parse html code from wicket application to Java. My application uses wicket and I found a method

> tester.getLastResponse().getDocument()

which does just that. However not all html code gets included there. When I saved this output I can see that there are places like

> < MARKUP FOR
>   com. ... .form.PlainCheckBoxPanel END
>   >

How can I make it parse the full html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you run your application in DEVELOPMENT mode and `org.apache.wicket.settings.DebugSettings#isOutputMarkupContainerClassName()` returns `true`.

Change it to PRODUCTION mode or call `org.apache.wicket.settings.DebugSettings#setOutputMarkupContainerClassName(false)`.